# number of eigenvalues = dimension of eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is this true in general? What about: number of negative eigenvalues = dimension of span(eigenectors for the negative eigenvalues)?

Or even more generally: number of eigenvalues greater than 4.3 = dimension of span(eigenvectors for the eigenvalues greater than 4.3)?

Is (number of negative eigenvalues) here distinct eigenvalues or not?

Any help would be much appreciated, as I cna't seem to find a proof anywhere (not even sure if it's true)

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on how you count. How many negative eigenvalues does $\begin{pmatrix}-42&0\\0&-42\end{pmatrix}$ have? And $\begin{pmatrix}-42&1\\0&-42\end{pmatrix}$?

Answer (score 5):

Not true. For the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
2 &1\\
0 &2\\
\end{bmatrix}
2 is an eigenvalue twice, but the dimension of the eigenspace is 1.

Roughly speaking, the phenomenon shown by this example is the worst that can happen. Without changing anything about the eigenstructure, you can put any matrix in Jordan normal form by basis-changes. JNF is basically diagonal (so the eigenspaces are exactly the coordinate axes/planes/whatever), except it can contain blocks like this one, with a repeated evalue on the diagonal, and 1s above the diagonal.

Comment: What if we're only counting distinct eigenvalues?

Comment: Then twice the 2x2 identity matrix (i.e., the example I provided with the "1" changed to "0") is a counterexample: 2 is an eigenenvalue once in this counting scheme, but the associated eigenspace is all of $R^2$, hence 2-dimensional. And for the "negative eigenvalues" question, you can just negate both of these examples to see that there's no hope there, either. If you're willing to count repeated eigenvalues, *and* your matrix is *symmetric*, then the Jordan form is also symmetric, hence diagonal, and each eigenspace's dimension really does equal the associated eigenvalue's multiplicity.

Comment: Many thanks. Why is it the case that, if M is symmetric, then the Jordan Normal form is too?

Comment: That's a little tricky. I should have been more specific: it's true if $M$ is a *real* symmetric matrix. In that case, it follows from Sylvester's Law of Inertia, which says that $M$ can be written as $Q^t D Q$, where $Q$ is orthonormal and $D$ diagonal. Since $Q$ is orthonormal, we can rewrite as $M = Q^{-1} D Q$, which means $D = QMQ^{-1}$; since a diagonal matrix is a Jordan form, it must be THE Jordan form. (I apologize for the brevity of this reply -- 500 characters isn't a lot to work with.)

Comment: I tried searching for Sylvester's law of Inertia and it seems to come in many different forms (with many different proofs). I'm not quite able to find that version. And also, are you saying that D is the jordan normal form (apart from permuting the diagonal entries)? So the JNF is diagonal, but why does that mean eigensapce dimension = associated eigenvalue's multiplicity?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_law_of_inertia); search for "statement in terms of eigenvalues". And yes, I'm saying that the resulting diagonal matrix is the JNF. That means that the JNF is symmetric. My previous answer was an argument that "M symmetric implies JNF(M) is symmetric", which is what you'd asked in the comment above (4/25, 9:37 PM). For the last step -- JNF diag -> dimension = multiplicity", see next comment.

Comment: Suppose the matrix is diag(-2, -2, 3, 3, 3, -6). Then the eigenspace for $-2$ has $e_1, e_2$ as a basis; that for 3 has $e_3, e_4, e_5$ as a basis, and that for $-6$ has $e_6$ as a basis. Presumably you see the general pattern here. A $k$-times repeated eigenvalue has $k$ different standard basis vectors in its eigenspace, so the dimension of that eigenspace is at *least* $k$. Summing over all eigenvalues, you'll see that it's also at most $k$. Hence, it's exactly $k$.